# CSS3 Transition Effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have recently been studying up a ton on CSS3, and I've made a design just for fun with a ton of unnecessary features and effects. Here it is:

http://wendyhenrichs.com/could/

If you take a look at my navigation bar at the top, you'll notice that when you hover over a link, it moves 7 pixels to the right in a smooth, transition motion.

But then notice, when your take your mouse off the link, it will just immediately hop back into its original position.

Is there any way to make it fade back into position in a smooth motion, as it moved before?

Comment: When I test it, it jumps forward on mouse over, and back on mouse out. That is, it never shows smooth transition. Don't know what this means, but thought you might like to know.

Comment: Link is down, making this a non-question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a way.. give it a `position` to transition back to

you already have the transition on the default `a` so just set the `nav a`s relative position to back to 0; it will need `position: relative` too, so if you just put `position: relative` on the default state, then you just manipulate the left co-ordinate on the hover state

```
#nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li a:focus,
#nav ul li a:active {
  color: white;
  left: 7px;
}
```

#### Working Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/yvR29/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The example you provided was very helpful!